# Read properties from git without using spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot

I am looking for a solution where a spring boot application could read data from separate git repository(ex: sampleData). Also if possible if there a way to reload or refresh data just like actuator/refresh whenever there is new data pushed to remote git repo (sampleData).I dont want a config server running for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a library for something like that. But I would like to recommend a solution:

- Integrate git apis' (rest) into your project.
- Keep track of your latest commit into the repository.
- Keep pinging your git repo api at regular interval.
- if there is a new commit into your remote git repository, pull and reload your data/app.

Check here: [github developer api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28)

**Or,**

*if you just want to reload data on a local repository or folder. Just use  [Java nio2 FileWatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)*

*`git` has nothing to do with java filewatcher.*